# Posting image in twitter with swift 2

Tags: json, swift, twitter, swift2

I want to post an image in twitter, im using swift 2. I tried many different ways and I can not fin the right code in twitter documentation. So far, the result in JSON is this

```
{
    "expires_after_secs" = 86400;
    image =     {
        h = 540;
        "image_type" = "image/png";
        w = 540;
    };
    "media_id" = 732352461227233281;
    "media_id_string" = 732352461227233281;
    size = 514691;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Twitter API document here:

`https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/media/upload`

You must provide the full range of parameters.

Parameters

```
**media** [required]: The raw binary file content being uploaded. Cannot be used with media_data.

**media_data** [required]: The base64-encoded file content being uploaded. Cannot be used with media.

**additional_owners** [optional]: A comma-separated list of user IDs to set as additional owners allowed to use the returned media_id in Tweets or Cards. Up to 100 additional owners may be specified.
```

Comment: I provided just media_data.
`let parameters = "media_data" : imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])]`